# Adding partitions to the external table in hive takes a lot of time

Tags: hive, partition, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I would like to know what is the best possible way(s) of adding partitions to the external table. I have a external table on S3 in hive with the partition as 
vehicle=/date=/hr=

---

Now new vehicle can be added at any time of day and there will be vehicles which will not have data for a couple of hours in a day or for couple of days.

Few possible solutions 
- msck reapir table : It takes a lot of time
- Add partition via script : I may not know when new vehicle gets created or which hour data is not there for a vehicle

How do generally people solve this problem of adding partitions to the external tables

Answer (score 1):

`msck reapir table` is a right way to do this. If it runs too slow, try to switch off stats autogather **before** repair table:

```
set hive.stats.autogather=false;
```

You can enable it again after recovering partitions.

Most probably you are hitting [HIVE-18743](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18743) or related bug. In my case this helped.

Comment: Yes msck repair table is a overhead. I am now doing an add partition on every event of file that is created using lambda function

Comment: @Nipun Yes, Lambda maybe a better solution