# Does msck repair trigger table statistics generation

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-partitions, hive-configuration

i would like to know whether running `msck repair <table>` on table will generate table statistics for CBO when:

`hive.cbo.enable=true`

`hive.stats.autogather=true`

or do i have to use `analyze <tablename> compute statistics`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can gather stats when running REPAIR. But it is considered as a bug because the REPAIR command runs unexpectedly slow in this case.

There are a number of related JIRAs:

[HIVE-18743](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18743) 
[HIVE-19489](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19489) 
[HIVE-17478](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17478) 
[SPARK-17063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17063)

`hive.stats.autogather=false` before REPAIR is a workaround.

Since it is considered like a bug, you better do not rely on this feature and 
do analyze when necessary.

Found this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57885181/2700344